# Building boost::log::formatter on runtime condition

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log

I want to build `boost::log::formatter` conditionally, however, formatter objects do not seem to behave as 'normal values'.

For example:

```cpp
auto sink = boost::log::add_console_log(std::clog);

auto format =
    expr::stream << expr::format_date_time(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f");

boost::log::formatter formatter = format;

if (condition) {

    auto t = "msg=" << expr::smessage;

    formatter <<= t;
}

sink->set_formatter(formatter);
```

However, `operator<<=` (or even `operator=` for that matter) doesn't seem to modify formatter object which is very surprising for me!

What is the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formatting streaming expression constructs a function object that will be executed when a log record is formatted into string. The function object type is final in the sense that you cannot modify it by adding new formatting statements to it. In fact, any streaming statement effectively creates a new formatter function object of a distinct type. `boost::log::formatter` is just a type erasure helper that encapsulates the formatter function object, similar to how `std::function` encapsulates a lambda function that you assign to it.

If you want to modify the formatter, you must create a new formatter that will have the original formatter as its left part and the added streaming statements on the right. This new formatter can then be assigned to `boost::log::formatter`.

```
auto sink = boost::log::add_console_log(std::clog);

boost::log::formatter formatter;

auto common_format =
    expr::stream << expr::format_date_time(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f");

if (condition) {
    auto format = common_format << "msg=" << expr::smessage;
    formatter = format;
} else {
    formatter = common_format;
}

sink->set_formatter(formatter);
```

Note that this will only work with streaming expressions. This will not work with Boost.Format-style formatters based on `boost::log::expressions::format`.

Also note that `condition` will be evaluated once - when the formatter is *constructed*, not when it is *executed* to format log records. If you want to test a condition when the formatter is executed then you should look into [conditional formatters](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/expressions.html#log.detailed.expressions.formatters.conditional).

Comment: Thank you very much! This is soo weird; why does formatter object even has overloaded operator `<<=` if it does nothing :(

Comment: Hm, I'm also not sure what should I do if I need two independent conditional blocks; it seems that type-erased formatter can't be used in a streaming expression.. How can I 'save' current state to modify it again?

Comment: @Amomum > why does formatter object even has overloaded operator `<<=` if it does nothing -- `boost::log::basic_formatter` (and its typedefs) don't have an `operator <<=`. If the code compiles then there must be an unrelated `operator <<=` that is being picked up by the compiler.

Comment: > How can I 'save' current state to modify it again? -- You cannot modify the formatter, only create a new one. Every condition you add doubles the number of formatter types you generate. One solution is to move your second condition and assignment to `boost::log::formatter` to a function template, and pass the result of the first condition to that function as an argument. That function template will be instantiated twice - once per condition branch, with its distinct formatter type.

Comment: Alternatively, if your format is highly dependent on a large number of conditions, you can implement your own formatter that will be better oriented to runtime configuration. Or use [parsed formatter](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/utilities.html#log.detailed.utilities.setup.filter_formatter).

Comment: Oh dear.. That looks very complicated for no obvious reason :) Thanks for clarification!

Comment: @Amomum As I said, the reason is that you cannot modify a type once it's defined. It's the same as you can't modify a C++ lambda body or a structure once it's defined. Expression templates are deliberately designed that way to aid optimizations. If you need a runtime structure, you need something else.

Comment: Okay, fair enough :)